# SQL - How do I get values where all of the values in another column are the same?

Tags: sql, oracle

Given a table like this:

```
PROJ| NAME | c_3  
----+------+----
 1  | ANN  | 10      
 2  | BOB  | 20     
 3  | CHAD | 15      
 4  | ANN  | 20      
 5  | ANN  | 30      
 6  | BOB  | 20      
 7  | BOB  | 20
```

I need to get the names of those where the value of c_3 is always the same. In this case the result would be CHAD (single entry) and BOB (c_3 is always 20) but not ANN (c_3) varies. I'm completely stuck and nothing I've tried comes close

Comment: Sample data is great, but can you also _specify_ the expected result the same way.

Comment: Seems pretty clear to me

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check all values of a column in a group to be same](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26377053/check-all-values-of-a-column-in-a-group-to-be-same)

Answer (score 1):

You wanted to see the names of those where the value of c_3 is always the same. So here is my simple query which will help you to resolve this

```
 SELECT Name 
 FROM 
 (
     SELECT 
         Name, 
         COUNT(DISTINCT C_3) Distinct_Counter
     FROM Table_Name
     GROUP BY Name
 )T WHERE T.Distinct_Counter = 1
```

Comment: worked perfectly thank you :)

Comment: @SamuelPimenta If it helps then please don't forget to accept the answer/give an upvote.

Comment: @Md.TarikulIslamSoikot You can get rid of the inner/outer queries by using the `HAVING` clause on the aggregate query, e.g. `select name from table_name group by name having count(distinct c_3) = 1;`

Comment: @Boneist Thanks for your suggestion. Obviously that will help a lot to simplify this query.